# ¿Como guardar fila especifica de una tabla de datos: contiene archivo adjunto y textos?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tengo una lista de datos en un tabla, donde cada fila tiene su respectivo *guardar*. Este botón guarda la fecha y documento adjunto.

Yo lo tengo así:

Cuando hago click en *guardar* y llamo a mi acción, ésta me trae todas las filas, por lo que tengo que hacer un `for` para crear criterios y que solo se guarde la fila donde hice click. Sin embargo creo que esta práctica está mal.

¿Existe alguna forma para que solo me traiga los datos de la fila donde hice el click en *guardar*?

Esta es mi codificación actual:

Página web:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Accion del Controlador:

```
public ActionResult GuardarCargoCierreAtencion(List<int> FgCargo, List<String> Mes,List<String> Periodo,
        List<int> CierreAtencionId, List<String> FechaCargo, List<HttpPostedFileBase> DireccionArchivo)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session["Usuario"] == null)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return JavaScript(string.Format("alert('Su sesión ha terminado, debe volver a iniciar sesión'); window.location.href='{0}'", Url.Action("IniciarSession", "Logueo")));
            }
            else return RedirectToAction("IniciarSession", "Logueo");
        }
        //EstablecimientoId = ((Usuario)Session["Usuario"]).Establecimiento.EstablecimientoId;
        UsuarioID = ((Usuario)Session["Usuario"]).UsuarioId;

        CierreAtencionAD CierreAtencion = new CierreAtencionAD();
        CierreAtencion CierreAt = new CierreAtencion();
       // ControlMedicoUdrEstablecimiento Save=new ControlMedicoUdrEstablecimiento();
        int cont = 0;
        if (DireccionArchivo != null)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase requestFile in DireccionArchivo)
            {

                if (requestFile != null)
                {

                    CierreAt = Guardar(CierreAtencionId.ElementAt(cont), FechaCargo.ElementAt(cont).ToString(), Mes.ElementAt(cont).ToString(), Periodo.ElementAt(cont).ToString(), requestFile);
                  //  errorMensaje = errorMensaje + "<br>" + "- " + Save.error + "\n";
                }                    
                cont++;
            }
        }
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("CierreGuardar", CierreAt);
        HttpContext.Session["Error"] = CierreAt.Error;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Deberías plantearte copiar el código fuente en la pregunta en vez de mostrar una captura de pantalla. El problema de las imágenes son dos: no se puede copiar el código para escribir la respuesta más rápido o hacer pruebas y si el enlace se pierde la pregunta no servirá para nada.

Comment: Lo único que guardás es el archivo? o se pueden modificar el resto de los campos?

Comment: Solo se deben modificar la fecha y el archivo, los demás parámetros lo necesito para mi store procedure.

Comment: Lo de recorrer qué se modificó no es buena idea. Usaste ventanas modales alguna vez?

Comment: En mvc no he usado modal, pero en otros lenguajes si, pero como lo solucionaría con modal, puedes explicarte completo @PabloClaus ?

Comment: Hace unos años implementé un sistema usando una ventana modal que se abria para que el usuario agregue un archivo. Una vez agregado, recargaba la grilla. Enviaba los id que necesitaba y guardaba en la base de datos el archivo. En el controlador tenía una acción exclusiva para el archivo, independiente de las modificaciones generales de la grilla. Si te interesa puedo poner el código como respuesta, pero vas a tener que modificarlo. Use Kendo UI para la ventana modal con el renderizado Razor.

Comment: @PabloClaus me gustaría ver tu código y como solucionaste el problema. Seguramente voy a tener que ajustarlo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Listo. Como te comenté vas a tener que adaptarlo. Cualquier duda comentame en la respuesta y trato de explicarte.

Answer (score 1):

En la vista con la grilla usaba este código (está simplificado).

Fijate que ocultaba los ids en la grilla que necesitaba para asociar los archivos al modelo. Capaz en tu caso no sea necesario.

```
 <td class="tabla-td">
   @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.IDPozo)
   @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.IDEnsayo)
     <input type="button" value="Agregar archivo" class="button" id="ButtonAdd" />
   @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Fecha)
 </td>
```

En la misma vista usaba la función `mostrarVentanaArchivo` para llamar la acción del controlador con los parametros que necesitaba

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").click(function () {
        var ensayo = $(this).prev("input:hidden").val();
        var fecha = $(this).next("input:hidden").val();
        var pozo = $(this).prev("input:hidden").prev("input:hidden").val();
        mostrarVentanaArchivo(ensayo, fecha, pozo);
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 function mostrarVentanaArchivo(ensayo, fecha, pozo) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Archivos")',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        traditional: true,
        data: { IDEnsayo: ensayo, Fecha: fecha, IDPozo: pozo}
    })
    .done(function (result) {
        // Display the section contents.
        $('#VentanaArchivos').html(result);
    })

}
</script>
```

En el controlador:

```
   public ActionResult Add(int IDEnsayo, string Fecha, int IDPozo)
    {
        DateTime FechaTemp = DateTime.Parse(Fecha);
        Ensayo Ensayo = new Ensayo { IDEnsayo = IDEnsayo, Fecha = FechaTemp, IDPozo = IDPozo };
        return PartialView(Ensayo);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Ensayo Ensayo, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile, int IDPozo)
    {
        if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var ensayo = new Ensayo { IDEnsayo = Ensayo.IDEnsayo };
            ensayo.Archivo.Longitud = uploadFile.ContentLength;
            ensayo.Archivo.Nombre = uploadFile.FileName;
            ensayo.Archivo.Tipo = uploadFile.ContentType;
            byte[] tempFile = new byte[uploadFile.ContentLength];
            uploadFile.InputStream.Read(tempFile, 0, uploadFile.ContentLength);
            ensayo.Archivo.Contenido = tempFile;
            ensayo.SaveArchivo();

            Log.Add(DateTime.Now, TipoLog.AsociacionArchivo, HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, "Asocia archivo " + ensayo.Archivo.Nombre);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", new {IDPozo = IDPozo });
    }
```